# Counterexample to open cover with Lindelöf boundaries being shrinkable in a regular space?

Tags: general-topology

In any regular space one may separate disjoint closed sets which are Lindelöf by neighborhoods. An analogous proof shows one may separate disjoint closed sets with Lindelöf boundaries by neighborhoods. This is equivalent to the shrinkability of every cover of a regular space by two open sets with Lindelöf boundaries.

**Theorem.** Every open cover with Lindelöf boundaries of a regular space is shrinkable.

Does the converse hold? I'm guessing it doesn't since we don't assume anything about the closedness of points, but can't get myself to an actual counterexample.

Comment: Which converse? Every shrinkable cover has Lindelöf boundaries, or if every open cover with Lindelöf boundaries is shrinkable then the space is regular?

Comment: @DanielFischer the latter.